# Unique by domains urls list

Tags: python, list

```
urls = ['http://www.doopa.pl/1','http://www.doopa.pl/2',
    'http://www.dupa2.pl/4/php.pl', 'http://www.dupa3.pl/4/php?gfdgfd=44',
    'www.dupa4.pl/4/php.pl']
```

This example list contains two urls on the same domain:

http://www.doopa.pl/1

http://www.doopa.pl/2

From this list (urls) i must make the second, unique list. Second list can only contains one url from one unique domain.

First list could contain even 100.000 urls and more.

What is pythonic way to achieve this ?

Comment: Not sure how 'Pythonic' it is, but use http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html to parse out the domain, then just check if each domain is already in the structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `urlparse.urlparse` and use the `netloc` member of the result.

```
>>> urls = ['http://www.doopa.pl/1','http://www.doopa.pl/2',
...     'http://www.dupa2.pl/4/php.pl', 'http://www.dupa3.pl/4/php?gfdgfd=44',
...     'www.dupa4.pl/4/php.pl']
>>> from urlparse import urlparse
>>> dict((urlparse(u).netloc, u) for u in urls).values()
['www.dupa4.pl/4/php.pl', 'http://www.dupa2.pl/4/php.pl', 'http://www.doopa.pl/2', 'http://www.dupa3.pl/4/php?gfdgfd=44']
```

Note that the result will contain the *last* URL for each domain listed in `urls`. If you want the first, then loop over `reversed(urls)` in the comprehension.

Comment: Thanks, that's what i wanted to know :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import urlparse

urls = ['http://www.doopa.pl/1','http://www.doopa.pl/2',
        'http://www.dupa2.pl/4/php.pl', 'http://www.dupa3.pl/4/php?gfdgfd=44',
        'www.dupa4.pl/4/php.pl']

domains = {}

for url in urls:
    if not url.startswith("http://"):
        # Woops this will screw up the parser. Lets clean that up
        url = "http://" + url
    parse = urlparse.urlparse(url)
    path = parse.path
    netloc = parse.netloc
    if netloc in domains:
        domains[netloc].append(path)
    else:
        domains[netloc  ] = [path]

print domains
```

You now have a dict of domains with the associate's paths.